# Sonata admin form mapper one-to-many relation with too many entries

Tags: types, model, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a performance problem with sonata.

I built a form with a one-to-many relation that works great between operation on several products, everything is fine in dev environment, but in production, I have 250000 products to be managed that makes queries very slow…
I have an ajax query to replace my selector's content according to the maker of the product, but the first call (which param all the CRUD logic) is far too long…

Here is my form mapper

```
->add( 'operationhasproducts', 'sonata_type_model',
        array(
             'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Operationhasproducts',
             'query' => $this->modelManager->createQuery('MyBundle\Entity\Product'),
             'multiple' => true,
             'by_reference' => false,
             'btn_add' => false,
             'required' => false
       )
)
```

How can I keep the logic without loading 250000 products on loading the page

I tried to put `'query'=> $this->modelManager->createQuery('MyBundle\Entity\Product')->setMaxResults(10),` the form displays but then the crud logic no longer works, I have a data transformation error

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[operationhasproducts] = [0 => 2739, 1 => 29217]

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "operationhasproducts": Could not find all matching choices for the given values

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Could not find all matching choices for the given values
```

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Something is unclear… is the first call loading the 250 000 products?

Comment: Yes, it loads everything. I also tried to param my services with , pager_type: simple. But it still freezes.

Comment: Also, please detail what you mean by "it didn't work"

Comment: when I put setMaxResults(10), the first call loads only 10 entries and the form is displayed. But the crud logic no longer works. I then have a data transform error

Comment: I edited the question trying to be as precise as possible

Comment: if you limit to 10 results without giving any ORDER BY clause, nothing guarantees you will get the same 10 results. That might be why there is a mismatch…

Comment: Ok, I thought that data validation only concerned the dataType, not the dataset… So what can I do? When I load all the values on the first call, it works because the next ajax dataset is contained in the first call. But how can I do with 250000 entries? I can't load them all so my only alternative is to tweak the validation logic… But I don't know how yet. Unless there is another way?

Comment: You should change the validation logic depending on the current product maker IMO. Read the sf doc about form events, maybe?

Comment: Maybe I will disable validation for this entry…